# run an app and switch to it via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, service, systemd

I'm currently running a python script as a systemd service. Is there any way to "switch" into the service and take control of the script? The script has a menu but runs calculations in the background in another thread. Most likely not, so is there a way to run a python script 24/7, start on boot, restart on crash etc (just like systemd service) but be able to take control of it after I connect to the server via SSH, so I can manipulate the app?

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try would be to edit the systemd configuration to launch the process in screen or tmux, then attach that when logging in via SSH.

For instance, in the systemd unit, you might have:

```
[Service]
Type=single
ExecStart=tmux new "command"
```

Using `Type=single` will treat the `tmux` command as the main process, which would be killed if you stop it with `systemctl stop systemprocess`

The `ExecStart=tmux new "command"` creates a new tmux session with the command inside of it.

You can then attach to it using `tmux attach` as the same user the systemd unit is running as (I believe this is root by default).

Comment: I've encountered a problem... first of all systemd requires absolute path, so I need to use ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new -s pythontest /home/pythontest/py.py .... however my python script loads a config that is in the same folder as the script, which doesn't work now, as it's being run from the /usr/bin folder, not /home/pythontest... I do have WorkingDirectory set to /home/pythontest but it seems to have no effect

Comment: when I manually do: tmux new -s pythontest -c /home/pythontest ./py.py a new session that loads config is working just fine, but when I do it (with the absolute path to tmux) via systemd, it just crashes

Comment: using ExecStart (even without WorkinDirectory in service, just to try) as follows:ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new -s pythontest -c /home/pythontest /home/pythontest/py.py produces same result (just a crash right after start), while the same command works when just pasted into shell

Comment: What does the output of `journalctl -u systemdunt` say? That should give you an idea as to what is wrong.

Comment: I'm getting a "open terminal failed: not a terminal" error, I tried looking for solution and found out that -d flag should work, however then I'm getting just "Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart."